# Position of cursor after org-tags-view search

Tags: org-mode, tags

I use org tags as my chief method of storing and retrieving notes. After I invoke `org-tags-view` I see that the cursor is at the top of the screen rather than on the first hit. Is this poor design or is there a  reason for this? I would like to have the cursor on the first hit so I can just hit `enter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit an RFE to the Org mode mailing list and wait; or you can add an after-advice to `org-tags-view` to make it move a couple of lines forward at the end. Add the following to your init file.

```el
(defun two-lines-forward (&optional _ _)
  (forward-line 2))

(advice-add 'org-tags-view :after #'two-lines-forward)
```

`two-lines-forward` has to have the same signature as the function it advises (i.e. `org-tags-view`). In this case, there are two optional arguments, but since `two-lines-forward` does not make any use of them, we use the underscore "ignore this argument" convention. See [How to advice-add a function with no arguments to a function that takes arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042843/how-to-advice-add-a-function-with-no-arguments-to-a-function-that-takes-argument) for another way to deal with that requirement.

For details on `advice`, see [Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).